# show/hide div caused content to jump up

Tags: jquery, css, show-hide

I have some jquery that hides and shows the nav at a certain point on page scroll. The only problem is that when the navs poisition is changed from relative to fixed it shifts all of the content on the page upwards to fill the space where the nav was. I can't seem to find a solution that works. Here is the script:

```
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 800) {
    $('nav a').css({
        "color": "#555"
    });
    $('header').css({
        "position": "fixed",
        "top": "0px",
        "background": "white"
    });
} else {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() <= 800) {
        $('nav a').css({
            "color": "white"
        });
        $('header').css({
            "position": "relative",
            "top": "0px",
            "background": "none"
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When doing this, you should always style the nav with `position: absolute;` before it becomes `fixed` after scrolling a certain amount. You'll need to style the rest of your content to allow space for the nav section (so it'll need to remain a fixed height) but you won't have any "jump" effect.

Answer (score 0):

Set:

```
position: absolute;
top:0; left:0;
```

Absolute position will make it above all the elements, then top & left can margin its position without disturbing other things on page...

Answer (score 0):

This is just an idea :

Try to specify `visibility` to `hidden` and make a clone of the header.

```
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 800) {
$('nav a').css({
    "color": "#555"
});
var $clone = $('header').clone();
$clone.css({
    "position": "fixed",
    "top": "0px",
    "background": "white"
 });
 $('header').css({"visibility": "hidden"});

} else {
 if ($(this).scrollTop() <= 800) {
    $('nav a').css({
        "color": "white"
    });
    $clone.hide();
    $('header').css({
        "position": "relative",
        "top": "0px",
        "background": "none",
        "visibility": "visible"
    });
 }
}
```